# How to make a bold and Italic uppercase Greek letter?

Tags: bold, greek, letters, italic

I have tried `$\mathit {\boldmath $\Omega$}$`, but it doesn't work really.

So, is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you perhaps want the `\varOmega` in bold?

[image: variant Omega]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

  $\bm{\varOmega}$

\end{document}
```

Note that in the following code

```
$\mathit {\boldmath $\Omega$}$
```

the first `$` switches into maths mode (assuming we were not already typesetting maths) and the second `$` switches *out* of maths mode. Then the next switches into it and the last switches out of it.

This means that `\boldmath` occurs *in* maths mode, causing an error, and `\Omega` occurs *outside* maths mode, causing another (except that TeX is quite confused by this point).

Compare (simplifying by dropping the italics):

```
$\Omega$ \boldmath $\Omega$
```

which produces:

[image: normal and bold]

Note that here the `\Omega`s are *in* maths mode, while the `\boldmath` is *outside* it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following from `bm` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

The following are \textbf{Bold} \textit{italic} Greek symbols:

\[
\bm{\mathit{\Omega \ \ \Gamma \ \ \Theta \ \ \Lambda} \, , ...}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it helps really. Your answer is identical to cfr's.